# JaCoCo specify tested method/class for coverage

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, code-coverage, jacoco

I have a Java project that uses `JUnit 4`, `Mockito 1.8.4` and `JaCoCo 0.7.1.201405082137` for testing.

I want to be able to specify, for each test, which methods/classes should be considered for code coverage (something like [`PHPUnit @covers annotation`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.covers)).

Is this achievable in the setup I'm using? Any alternatives that I could use to do this?

Comment: As far as I know [JaCoCo does not support annotations](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/14), but it offers [include/exclude command line options for the agent](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html) that decorates the bytecode before runtime.